# Approach on sum of $\binom{10+r}{r}\cdot\binom{20-r}{10-r}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

The problem: Find $$\sum_{r=0}^{10} \binom{10+r}{r}\cdot\binom{20-r}{10-r}$$

I do not even know how to approach this problem. None of the standard binomials or their combinations that I consider like $(1+x)^n$ or $(1-x)^{-n}$ seem to work. Would anyone please provide a hint on how to approach this?

This is expected to be solved by only using high school techniques and considering basic polynomials of the form $(1+x)^n$ and $(1+x)^{-n}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, use the identity
$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n - k}$$
to simplify the sum to
$$\sum_{r = 0}^{10} \binom{10 + r}{10} \binom{20 - r}{10}.$$
Now, using the convention that $\binom nk = 0$ if $k < 0$ or $k > n$, this can be simplified even further into
$$\sum_{r = -10}^{20}\binom{10 + r}{10} \binom{20 - r}{10} = \sum_{s = 0}^{30} \binom{s}{10}\binom{30 - s}{10},$$
where we've made the substitution $s = r + 10$. This sum count up the number of ways we can split a line of $30$ balls into a left and right group and choose $10$ balls from each group. Another way to do this would be to choose $21$ balls out of a line of $31$ balls, and split the groups according to the $11$th ball chosen (removing it from the line). This means that the answer is $$\binom{31}{21} = \binom{31}{10} = \boxed{44352165}.$$

Comment: Very nice. I did something very similar but messed up near the end by using $\binom{30}{20}$ instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The part of changing the limits from -10 to 20 never occurred to me. The balls analogy was really eye opening too.

Answer (score 3):

Your sum is an instance of the [Rothe-Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity)

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{x}{x + rz} \binom{x + rz}{r} \frac{y}{y+(n-r)z} \binom{y+(n-r)z}{n-r} = \frac{x+y}{x+y+nz} \binom{x+y+nz}{n} \tag{1}$$ for the choice $$x = y = 11, \quad n = 10, \quad z = 1.$$  In particular, this yields
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^{10} \binom{10+r}{r} \binom{20-r}{10-r} 
&= \sum_{r=0}^{10} \frac{11}{11+r} \binom{11+r}{r} \frac{11}{21-r} \binom{21-r}{10-r} \\
&= \frac{22}{32} \binom{32}{10} \\
&= \binom{31}{10}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for this identity. Though I guess it's a real monster to memorize and apply correctly, especially at the level I am.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using two common binomial identities which might also be of interest.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{10}}\color{blue}{\binom{10+r}{r}\binom{20-r}{10-r}}
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{-11}{r}\binom{-11}{10-r}(-1)^r(-1)^{10-r}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{-22}{10}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{31}{10}=44\,352\,165}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$.
- In (2) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*
  $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{s}{k}\binom{t}{n-k}=\binom{s+t}{n}$ which corresponds to $(1+x)^s(1+x)^t=(1+x)^{s+t}$.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful solution, thank you so much! Could never have thought of converting from positive to negative exponents. Could you maybe explain the thought process that led you to try that?

Comment: @PopularPower: You're welcome. Many thanks for your nice comment. :-) A change of sign of the upper index $\binom{q+r}{r}$ to $\binom{-q-1}{r}(-1)^r$ comes into mind, when we see the variable $r$ being part of the lower index *and* upper index and we want to eliminate it from the upper index. This is a *[recurrent theme](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A132007+vandermonde+disguise)* in connection with the Chu-Vandermonde identity.